# Javascript/jQuery execution order question

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery to try and construct a table for a web app from a JSON object (using the async `getJson` call), and I am having difficulty getting to the bottom of the order of execution.

My JS is:

```
//create table header
$('#peopleDirectory').append(
    "<table><thead><tr><th>column header!</th>"
    +"</tr></thead><tbody>"
);

//iterate through list to create table row:
$.each(jsonArray.members, function(i, membObj) {
    $('#peopleDirectory').append(
            "<tr>"
            + "<td>" + membObj.name + "</td>"
            + "</tr>"
    );
});

//end table
$('#peopleDirectory').append("</tbody></table>");
```

I create the table and the header row, and then iterate the returned JSON to create the table rows, before closing the table. However, if I use the jQuery `$('#peopleDirectory').html()` then it produces the table header, then closes the table, and then appends the rows from the JSON (and the table does not appear correctly)

Can anyone help me out with why its executing the appends in this order?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem here is probably that you can't append partial HTML to an element like you're doing. When you append `<table><tbody>`, the browser will actually close the tags too. Then, when you append `tr`s etc., it's no longer inside the table, and the browser will again attempt to correct it, generating broken markup.

You need to first *construct the entire markup* and only after that append it.

Something like this should work:

```
var html = "<table><thead><tr><th>column header!</th>"
         + "</tr></thead><tbody>";

$.each(jsonArray.members, function(i, membObj) {
    html += "<tr>"
          + "<td>" + membObj.name + "</td>"
          + "</tr>";
});

html += "</tbody></table>";

$('#peopleDirectory').append(html);
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks - I was looking down the wrong path thinking it was executing in a strange order. That has worked perfectly.