# Adding jQuery .click() to dynamically created HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my web app, I am dynamically creating a live feed using jQuery to parse a JSON object and dynamically creating table rows in html (see my earlier question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5773976/258813) for an example )

Every table row I dynamically create from the JSON object, I add an image (using a standard html img tag) - What I want to do now, is create a .click() function that performs an async ajax call when that image is clicked.

so, if my code that creates the table rows dynamically looks like this:

```
var html = "<tr>"
            + "<td><img class=\"status_refresh\" src=\"/refresh.png\" id=\"refresh_id\"/></td>"
            + "</tr>";

$('#peopleDirectory').append(html);
```

In my JSP, where the peopleDirectory div is defined, and the html will be appended, I have the following javascript:

```
$('.status_refresh').click(function () { 
    console.log($(this).attr('id')); 
});
```

But nothing is happening when I click.. can anyone advise what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `click` event is only bound to objects that exist at the time of binding. To bind the event to all existing **and future** objects, use the `live` method.  [Source Link](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

> Description: Attach a handler to the
>   event for all elements which match the
>   current selector, now and in the
>   future.

```
$('.status_refresh').live('click', function () { 
    console.log($(this).attr('id')); 
});
```

Comment: At this time, LIVE is deprecated and should be replaced with `.on()`

Answer (score 6):

`live()` will work, but I would recommend using [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) with your container:

```
$('#peopleDirectory').delegate('.status_refresh', 'click', function(){ 
     //do stuff
}
```

`live()` attaches a click handler to the `document` and bubbles all the way up for each event. `delegate()` stops the event bubbling at the container you specify. The only gotcha of `delegate()` is that the container element you specify must already exist in the DOM. However if you're not sure if the container is going to exist or not, you can just use `$('body').delegate()`.

Answer (score 2):

1. put all your bind functions in a function...
2. now call this function inside the `$(document).load()` and as well as the success function of the ajax via which you are adding the html to the DOM

NOTE* - Calling this function inside the Success method is necessary because ajax is synchronous and success method is called only after the response comes therefor these functions will get binded if called after the addition of html to the DOM

Answer (score 1):

try this (ID's can not be equal):

([example](http://jsfiddle.net/adescalzo/p7xPz/))

html:

```
<table>
</table>
<br />
<button>add</button>
```

js:

```
var 
    idAdd = 0,
    addToTable = function() {

        var
            img = $('<img />'),
            td = $('<td />'),
            tr =  $('<tr />');

        img
            .addClass('status_refresh')
            .attr('src', 'http://jsfiddle.net/img/top-bg.png')
            .attr('name', 'refresh_id')
            .attr('id', 'refresh_id_' + idAdd)
            .bind('click', function(ev) {

                console.log($(this).attr('id')); 

            });

        idAdd++;

        td.append(img);
        tr.append(td);

        return tr;

    };

$('button').bind('click', function(event){
    $('table').append(addToTable());
});
```

Comment: I like your javascript coding-style! :)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what Dutchie432 and Jason said, you can also attach your click event after appending the html. That would also work >

```
var html = "<tr>"
            + "<td><img class=\"status_refresh\" src=\"/refresh.png\" id=\"refresh_id\"/></td>"
            + "</tr>";

$('#peopleDirectory').append(html);

//and now attach the event handler again
$('.status_refresh').click(function () { 
    console.log($(this).attr('id')); 
});
```